# Check form with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I'm trying to do a little project, but I don't know how to do it. My JQuery is affecting both forms.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[value='wrong']").click(function() {

    $(this).parent()
    .addClass("wrong")
    .siblings().removeClass("right wrong");

    //$("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
  });

  $("input[value='right']").click(function() {
    $(this).parent()
    .addClass("right")
    .siblings().removeClass("right wrong");

    $("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
  });

  $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    $(this).parent()
    .siblings().removeClass("right wrong");

    $("input[type='radio']").prop('checked', false);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form3">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Form 1</legend>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option1">A</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option2">B</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option3">C</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option4">D</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="right" class="option5">E</label>
    <br />
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <div class="slider"></div>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>


<form class="form3">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Form 2</legend>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option1">A</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option2">B</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option3">C</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option4">D</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="right" class="option5">E</label>
    <br />
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <div class="slider"></div>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I'd like to know how to make it checks the first checkbox whenever I select a radio from the first form, if I uncheck the first checkbox it uncheck the checked radio from the first form. The same thing for the second form without affect both forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you optimizing your code and separating logics to two blocks ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fvb0gxzu/2/)). You will end up with an increase of event listeners, but this code follows the [Separation of concerns](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Separation_of_concerns) principle allowing better support and reusability.
This code also makes checkbox-radios link to not be dependant on the markup, which is a good thing too. You can even go ahead and make a jQuery plugin by doing some minor tweaks, but it is out of scope for now.

#### First block

Responsible for handling "right" and "wrong" classes;

```
// find all inputs
$('input')
    // take only those with value set to 'right' or 'wrong'
    .filter(function() {
        return ['right', 'wrong'].indexOf($(this).val()) !== -1
    })
    // bind to the change event
    .on('change', function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this
            .parent()
            // set the parent class - right or wrong,
            // depending on this input's value
            .addClass($this.val())
            // remove classes from siblings
            .siblings()
            .removeClass('right wrong');
    })

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('form').find('label').removeClass('right wrong');
});
```

#### Second block

Responsible for linking checkboxes and radios

```
// find all checkboxes with data-radio-link attribute set
$('input[type="checkbox"][data-radio-link]')
    // for each found checkbox
    .each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        // find all the linked radios using
        // the query from data-radio-link attribute
        var linkedRadios = $($this.data().radioLink);

        // remember those radios for future use
        $this.data('linkedRadios', linkedRadios)

        // check the checkbox when
        // any radio becomes checked
        linkedRadios.on('change', function() {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                $this.prop("checked", true);
            }
        });
    })
    // when the user changes checkbox value
    .on('change', function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        // if it becomes unchecked
        if (!$this.prop("checked")) {
            // find the linked radios that is checked and uncheck it
            $this.data().linkedRadios.filter(':checked').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
```

#### HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" data-radio-link="#form-1 input[name='option']"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the relative checkbox/radio

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input[value='wrong']").click(function() {

    $(this).parent()
    .addClass("wrong")
    .siblings().removeClass("right wrong");
    
    //$("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
  });

  $("input[value='right']").click(function() {
    $(this).parent()
    .addClass("right")
    .siblings().removeClass("right wrong");
    
    $(this).closest('form').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
  });

  $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    $(this).parent()
    .siblings().removeClass("right wrong");
    
    $(this).closest('form').find("input[type='radio']").prop('checked', false);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form3">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Form 1</legend>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option1">A</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option2">B</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option3">C</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option4">D</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="right" class="option5">E</label>
    <br />
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>


<form class="form3">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Form 2</legend>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option1">A</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option2">B</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option3">C</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option4">D</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="right" class="option5">E</label>
    <br />
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The snippet covers below points.

1. When a radio button will checked checkbox of respected form will be checked and on un-check of checkbox radio button will be unchecked of respected form.
2. On check of checkbox first radio button of respected form will be checked.

I have implemented code for both forms please check working snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input[value='wrong']").click(function() {

    $(this).parent()
    .addClass("wrong")
    .siblings().removeClass("right wrong");

    //$("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
    $(this).closest('form').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
  });

  $("input[value='right']").click(function() {
    $(this).parent()
    .addClass("right")
    .siblings().removeClass("right wrong");

    $(this).closest('form').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
  });

  $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    $(this).parent()
    .siblings().removeClass("right wrong");

    if($(this). prop("checked") == false){
      $(this).closest('form').find("input[type='radio']").prop('checked', false);
                                          
    }else{
    
      $(this).closest('form').find("input[type='radio']:first").prop('checked', true);
      
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form3">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Form 1</legend>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option1">A</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option2">B</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option3">C</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option4">D</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="right" class="option5">E</label>
    <br />
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>


<form class="form3">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Form 2</legend>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option1">A</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option2">B</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option3">C</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option4">D</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="right" class="option5">E</label>
    <br />
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```